# How to optimize following SQL Query?

Tags: sql, oracle

Query is

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.X1, A.X2, A.X3, TO_DATE(A.EVNT_SCHED_DATE,'DD-Mon-YYYY') AS EVNT_SCHED_DATE,
               A.X4, A.MOVEMENT_TYPE, TRIM(A.EFFECTIVE_STATUS) AS STATUS, A.STATUS_TIME, A.TYPE, 
               A.LEG_NUMBER,
               CASE WHEN A.EFFECTIVE_STATUS='BT' THEN 'NLT'
                    WHEN A.EFFECTIVE_STATUS='NLT' THEN 'NLT'
                    WHEN A.EFFECTIVE_STATUS='MKUP' THEN 'MKUP'
               END  AS STATUS
FROM PHASE1.DY_STATUS_ZONE A
WHERE A.LAST_LEG_FLAG='Y'
                   AND SCHLD_DATE>='01-Apr-2019'--TO_DATE(''||MNTH_DATE||'','DD-Mon-YYYY') 
                AND SCHLD_DATE<='20-Feb-2020'--TO_DATE(''||TILL_DATE||'','DD-Mon-YYYY') 
                AND A.MOVEMENT_TYPE  IN ('P')
                AND (EXCEPTIONAL_FLAG='N' OR EXCEPTION_TYPE='5') ---------SS
```

PHASE1.DY_STATUS_ZONE has 710246 records in it , Please guide if this query can be optimized ?

Comment: Is SELECT DISTINCT needed?

Comment: I suppose `SCHLD_DATE` is of date type, then replace your extremum literals as in `SCHLD_DATE between date'2019-04-01' and date'2020-02-20'` in order to be able to benefit your index on that column.

Comment: What are the datatype of your `EVNT_SCHED_DATE` and `SCHLD_DATE` columns?

Comment: Can you show the execution plan? and how many rows is this query returning?

Comment: `TO_DATE(A.EVNT_SCHED_DATE,'DD-Mon-YYYY') AS EVNT_SCHED_DATE` look like SCHLD_DATE is varchar as well and not date. Please confirm that SCHLD_DATE is data_type date. Please add information how selective `LAST_LEG_FLAG`, `MOVEMENT_TYPE` and `EXCEPTIONAL_FLAG, EXCEPTION_TYPE` are

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding an index which covers the `WHERE` clause:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON PHASE1.DY_STATUS_ZONE (LAST_LEG_FLAG, SCHLD_DATE, MOVEMENT_TYPE,
    EXCEPTIONAL_FLAG, EXCEPTION_TYPE);
```

Depending on the cardinality of your data, the above index may or may not be used.

Comment: Then I don't know of any other to speed up your query.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be the `select distinct`.  This can be hard to optimize because it removes duplicates.  Even if no rows are duplicated, Oracle still does the work.  If it is not needed remove it.

For your particular query, I would write it as:

```
WHERE A.LAST_LEG_FLAG = 'Y' AND
      SCHLD_DATE >= DATAE '2019-04-01 AND
      SCHLD_DATE <= DATE '2020-02-20' AND
      A.MOVEMENT_TYPE = 'P' AND
      EXCEPTIONAL_FLAG IN ('N', '5')
```

The date formats don't affect performance.  Just readability and maintainability.

For this query, the optimal index is probably:  `(LAST_LEG_FLAG, MOVEMENT_TYPE, SCHLD_DATE, EXCEPTIONAL_FLAG)`.  The last two columns might be switched, if `EXCEPTIONAL_FLAG` is more selective than `SCHLD_DATE`.

However, if this returns many rows, then the `SELECT DISTINCT` will be the gating factor for the query.  And that is much more difficult to optimize.